# Trocar de view pelo controller (Ng-Click)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

Estou utilizando o ng-route para desenvolver uma single page application com o angularjs+laravel. Estou com um problema na parte de trocar de view por meio do ng-click e o controller.
Tenho um botão em uma view, e gostaria que ao fosse clicado ele redirecionasse para outra view, levando uma informação (id).

Esse é meu arquivo de rotas do angular. Quero redirecionar da página Gerenciar Colaboradores para a página Novo Colaborador.

```html
angular.module('registrosGerais')
   .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
            controller: ''
          })
          .when('/colaboradores', {
            templateUrl: 'views/colaboradores/gerenciarcolaboradores.html',
            controller: 'colaboradoresController'
          })
          .when('/colaboradores/novocolaborador', {
            templateUrl: 'views/colaboradores/novocolaborador.html',
            controller: 'colaboradoresController'
          })
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/colaboradores'
          });
      });
```

Esse é o botão que deve ser clicado para que redirecionar a nova view.

```html
<button id="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
        ng-click="toggle('add', 0, '/#/colaboradores/novocolaborador')">Novo Colaborador</button>
```

Esse é meu controller.

```html
app.controller('colaboradoresController', function($scope, $http, API_URL) {
    
    $http.get(API_URL + "colaboradores")
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.tbcolaborador = response;
            });

    $scope.toggle = function(modalstate, id, $location) {
        $scope.modalstate = modalstate;

        $location.path('/#/colaboradores/novocolaborador');
}
```

A troca de view deveria ser feita levando uma informação (0 caso for adicionar um novo) e o id caso seja um colaborador já existente. Desde ja agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o controller é descartado na mudança de rota, uma forma é preparar seu config router para receber o parâmetro id na própria url.

```
.when('/colaboradores/novocolaborador/:id', {
              templateUrl: 'views/colaboradores/novocolaborador.html',
              controller: 'colaboradoresController'
            })
```

Assim, você poderá passar opcionalmente o id pela url (concatenando com a variável, por exemplo):

```
$scope.toggle = function(modalstate, id, $location) {
    $scope.modalstate = modalstate;

    $location.path('/colaboradores/novocolaborador/' + id);
```

...e recuperar o mesmo quando na outra view, através do $routeParams. Não esqueça de injetar esse serviço no seu controller.

```
var id = $routeParams.id;
```

Comment: Beleza, entendi essa explicação. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer a troca de view, o "$location.path" parece não estar funcionando...

Comment: Hmm, acredito que aquela hashtag não seja necessária. Tenta usar apenas '/colaboradores/novocolaborador/', se funcionar eu edito a resposta.

Comment: funcionou, valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Gostaria de saber como recuperar o id quando ja estiver na outra view. Você disse através do $routeParams, porem se eu ja estiver na outra view, com um novo controller, o que devo fazer para recuperar esse id? Criar uma função que recupera o id? onde devo chamar essa função, no início da view?

Comment: Consegui recuperar esse id por meio de um botão na nova view(fiz apenas para teste), porem gostaria de fazer isso automaticamente, quando ele entrar na view ele ja recuperar o id pelo routeparams...

Comment: Uma forma é você criar uma função e já chamar ela no início do seu controller, assim ela será executada na abertura da tela. Você verifica se $routeParams.id existe e, se existir, atribui o valor para a variável que deseja (se for usar na view, ela deve estar no $scope).

Comment: Cara fiz o seguinte funcao no meu controller: http://freetexthost.com/p3rx05ptjb Chamei ela no inicio da minha view {{recuperarId()}} porem ela está sendo executada infinitamente, acredito que seja por que a view é atualizada toda hora. Eu queria saber se existe algum "metodo construtor" da view, para que eu possa recuperar o id somente uma vez.

Comment: Não há necessidade de chamar a função pela view. Está sendo executada muitas vezes porque, da forma como você fez, ela é executada a cada ciclo do Angular. Uma forma simples é chamar ela no início do seu controller mesmo: http://freetexthost.com/6on6bb5zc1